# Material not working in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

[image: cycles]
The meterial only works in eevee. And in cycles it's only blue. I'm trying to make RGB strips, but they only work in eevee. I'm using the spline paramter in geometry nodes and passing it trough to the shader editor. Can someone pls help me.
[image: eevee]

Comment: i think i got that problem as well. Try using to use the group output for the color, that should work.